# fullcalendar colored same td?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is possible change background-color on same td in fullcalendar? 
for example: I like have blue beckground at Mo 10:00-14:00 and green beckground at Tu 9:30-11:30.

I visit: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=144&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

But it is possible now and how?

P.S: Sorry, I have bad English :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we could have a little more information about it JGB146? I am currently looking for this to be done: [FullCalendar: Change agendaDay background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895077/fullcalendar-change-agendaday-background-color)

you asked for a code snippet but it really is a basic calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    events: "/HRV/GetEvents",
                    lazyFetching : false,
                    minTime: 9,
                    maxTime: 22,
                    firstHour: 9,
                    firstDay: 1,
                    slotMinutes: 15
});
```

Would love to be able to specify another option that goes like:

```
workingTimeRange: [ 
   {
      start: 9,
      end: 12,
      className: 'morningJob'
   },
   {
      start: 13,
      end: 17,
      className: 'afterNoonJob'
   }
]
```

That would be very useful of a feature.. I would implement my own but I am very new to jQuery/fullCalendar.