# FullCalendar: Change agendaDay background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

While I have seen this question asked, I haven't seen the answer. I just want to be able to color the `background-color` of the `TD` from a certain range..

Say I have my calendar that has slot minutes every 15 minutes and from 9am to 9pm, I would like to only color differently 10am to 3pm.

This information would be coming from a feed but that is not an issue. I haven't found the `TD`s relating to a set time inside the calendar. Perhaps I missed something? :) I am rather new to `jQuery` and `fullCalendar`.

Also, another quick question that is unrelated to the main one:

- Is it possible from an event handler to get the `id` of the calendar that launched it? I have multiple calendars on my page to simulate something like a Gantt view. This will let me be able to fetch the right feed and populate the right events.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

here is the feature request for your first question:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=144
make sure to star it to receive updates. thanks

Comment: That would be a great feature.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote some simple annotation support to do this kind of feature, it can be found from

https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar

Hopefully it gets to be merged to official branch at some point

Annotations can be added like this:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ....
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            }
        ],
        annotations: [{
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 15, 30),
                title: 'My 1st annotation', // optional
                cls: 'open', // optional
                color: '#777777', // optional
                background: '#eeeeff' // optional
            }, { next annotation }, ...]        
    });

})
```

Full example how to use the annotations can be found here:
https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar/blob/master/demos/annotations.html

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful, however do you know how to make it work with the resource addon? austinb AT inn-soft DOT com if you would email me, i can explain more? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks do you have this addon for the newest version of fullcalendar 1.6.1?

Comment: @Mike, I just updated it to be based on latest fullcalendar. Now it is there.

Comment: @AustinBest did you get it fixed with resource view? If yes, can you please share the solution with me?

Comment: Yes, the answer is https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=144 in that post. I cant remember exactly where but i found a way to make it all work from there.

Comment: @AustinBest | Thanks it worked. 
I've one last problem now. When there are many resources in my resource view, the view gets squeezed. Did you face the same problem? May be you can help me with that too?

Comment: Would need to see it to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I need this feature in a project I am working now. This is a school project where I have to highlight the background with a red color if that day is a holiday event + the weekends. Please note that here all Saturdays are not holidays. Some school have holidays only on 2nd Saturday or in some schools a random Saturdays will be chosen as a working day.

Somehow I overcame this problem even though it is not an elegant solution.

On version 1.5.1 at line number 2291 add this line

```
var refDate = typeof(window.holidays)!='undefined'?window.holidays:[]; //Quick and dirty fix
```

From 2300 to 2304 replace the lines with the following code

```
if (+date == +today) {
    cell.addClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
}else if($.inArray(+date, refDate)!=-1){ //Added by me
    cell.addClass(tm + '-state-error');  //Added by me
}else{
    cell.removeClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
    cell.removeClass(tm + '-state-error'); //Added by me
}
```

Before calling the full calender, you need to create an array of dates converted into js date objects then converted into long integer by adding a + symbol in front of it, like this

```
var holidayArray = ['2011-06-26','2011-07-03','2011-07-10','2011-07-17','2011-07-24','2011-07-31'];
    window.holidays = [];
    for(var i=0; i<holidayArray.length;i++){
        holidays.push(+(mysqlDateToJSDate(holidayArray[i])));
    }
```

Finally I found a js function which converts mysql dates into js date objects.

```
function mysqlDateToJSDate(date) {
    var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])$/;
    var parts=date.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3").split(' ');
    return new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],0,0,0);
}
```

After calling the full calendar, don't forget to delete the global variable.

I know that creating a global variable is not a nice thing. But considering the full calendar is very active with frequent bug fixing and new features, I dont want to meddle too much into the code. I don't know how to pass the variable in as an option and easily get it where I want.

This has been done only on month view. We need to do the same on other views too...

Can't post the preview but you can see it [here](http://campus-soft.com/calendar-preview.png).

Comment: I was requesting it for agendaDay view for hours as opposed to day on/off. But I appreciate you taking the time, it is a step in the right direction.

Comment: From other posts, I assume that doing so in day view is easier with some simple tweaking, but very difficult on week view because each slot does not have its own separate cell. Let us hope that soon the fix comes from the author.

Answer (score 0):

I took the solution of @Jegatheesh and changed it to not access a global variable and use the built-in formatting. This is against 1.5.3

```
--- i/fullcalendar.js
+++ w/fullcalendar.js
@@ -29,6 +29,7 @@ var defaults = {
                right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        weekends: true,
+       holidays: [],

        // editing
        //editable: false,
@@ -2301,8 +2302,11 @@ function BasicView(element, calendar, viewName) {
                        }
                        if (+date == +today) {
                                cell.addClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
+                               cell.removeClass(tm + '-holiday');
+                       }else if ($.inArray(formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), calendar.options.holidays) != -1) {
+                               cell.addClass(tm + '-holiday');
                        }else{
-                               cell.removeClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today');
+                               cell.removeClass(tm + '-state-highlight fc-today ' + tm + '-holiday');
                        }
                        cell.find('div.fc-day-number').text(date.getDate());
                        if (dowDirty) {
```

It introduces the `fc-holiday` css class on the `td` element.

Performanced could be improved if we format the holidays array items into a timestamp and then call `$.inArray(+date, calendar.options.holidays)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty proof-of-concept that works on the latest version 'agenda-views.html' demo file in week view. It requires datejs with time.js (for TimeSpan) and does not currently work with scrolling, but could easily be tweaked. Also see the full page gist: https://gist.github.com/3005635

```
var resAvail = [
    {
        DayOfWeek: 0,
        Start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 0),
        End: new Date(y, m, d, 17, 30)
    },
    {
        DayOfWeek: 1,
        Start: new Date(y, m, d, 9, 0),
        End: new Date(y, m, d, 19, 30)
    },
    {
        DayOfWeek: 4,
        Start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
        End: new Date(y, m, d, 20, 00)
    }
]

var view = calendar.fullCalendar('getView');
var slotHeight = view.getSlotHeight();
var slotMins = calendar.fullCalendar('option', 'slotMinutes');
var minTime = calendar.fullCalendar('option', 'minTime');
var slotTop = $('.fc-agenda-slots').offset().top - $('.fc-agenda-days').offset().top;

// rip through days of week
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (r = 0; r < resAvail.length; r++) {
        var currentRes = resAvail[r];
        if (currentRes.DayOfWeek == i) {
            addAvailBlock(currentRes);
        }
    }
}

function addAvailBlock(currentRes) {
    var dayColumn = getDayColumn(i);
    var $availBlock = $('<div class="avail-block"></div>');
    dayColumn.append($availBlock);
    $availBlock.css('width', $availBlock.parent().css('width'));

    // Where we start the availability block
    var dayStart = Date.parse(currentRes.Start.toString('MM/dd/yyyy') + ' ' + minTime);
    var startOffsetSpan = new TimeSpan(currentRes.Start - dayStart);
    var startOffsetMins = startOffsetSpan.getMinutes() + (startOffsetSpan.getHours() * 60);
    var startOffsetSlots = startOffsetMins / slotMins;
    var startOffsetHeight = startOffsetSlots * slotHeight;

    var blockSpan = new TimeSpan(currentRes.End - currentRes.Start);
    var blockMins = blockSpan.getMinutes() + (blockSpan.getHours() * 60);
    var blockSlots = blockMins / slotMins;
    var blockHeight = blockSlots * slotHeight;
    $availBlock.css('top', slotTop + startOffsetHeight).css('height', blockHeight);
}

function getDayColumn(dayOfWeek) {
    switch (dayOfWeek) {
        case 0:
            return $('.fc-sun');
        case 1:
            return $('.fc-mon');
        case 2:
            return $('.fc-tue');
        case 3:
            return $('.fc-wed');
        case 4:
            return $('.fc-thu');
        case 5:
            return $('.fc-fri');
        case 6:
            return $('.fc-sat');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the gist link is dead... could you fix it, your solution would be great for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since version 2.2, you can use [Background Events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: '2014-11-10',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    events: [
        {
            start: '2014-11-10T10:00:00',
            end: '2014-11-10T16:00:00',
            rendering: 'background'
        }
    ]
});
```