# dayRender for agendaWeek

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In version 1.6 of Arshaw's fullcalender plugin he added the dayRender callback.

This callback only works for basicweek and basicday view.
But I need this callback for agendaDay and agendaWeek.

I like to change the background color of a special cell.
For example, for next monday 8.00 am to 11.00 am in red.

Any callbacks I can use?

Answer (score 0):

There are not any callbacks you can use. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895077/fullcalendar-change-agendaday-background-color) and get the idea, but it is based in a previous version of fullcalendar

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple solution. 
On 1.6 version of fullCalendar.js on line 3266 i add this line of code:

```
trigger('dayRender', t, date, $(bodyCell));
```

and that make dayRender to trigger as event with same parameters (I use the event for coloring bg of days cells)

That line goes inside the for `colCnt` inside `updateCells()`,  just above of the code `setDayID(headCell.add(bodyCell), date)`;

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.6, there is no direct callback method to do it. If you are using fullcalendar.min.js, you can do it by creating a function like :-

```
function yourfunction(currentDate)
{
    // your code
}
```

and place it above the

```
<script src="/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then find the code "l(){var t,e,n,r,a=f(new Date);" in fullcalendar.min.js and call your function before closing tag of function "l". Your code will look like this :-

```
l(){var t,e,n,r,a=f(new Date);if(Qe){var o=un(N(0),Ke);Je?o+=Ge:o=Ge+o,ee.find(".fc-week-number").text(o)}for(t=0;Le>t;t++)r=N(t),e=ne.eq(t),e.html(un(r,$e)),n=ae.eq(t),+r==+a?n.addClass(Ye+"-state-highlight fc-today"):n.removeClass(Ye+"-state-highlight fc-today"),yourfunction(r)==false?n.addClass("fc-disabled"):n.removeClass('fc-disabled'),$(e.add(n),r)}
```

I am adding class to disable the day. Good luck..!!