# FullCalendar Annotations

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

With current version of [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is it possible to use annotations as mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895077/fullcalendar-change-agendaday-background-color/#answer-13579812)? See in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maykonn/Ppnw3/), that is not working, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        annotations: [{
            start: new Date(y, m, d-2, 13, 30),
            end: new Date(y, m, d-2, 14, 00),
            title: 'Blocked Day',
            cls: 'open',
            color: '#777777',
            background: '#000'
        }],
        events: [{
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
            end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
            allDay: false
        }]
    });     
});
```

Comment: Did you get this to work? The accepted answer doesn't seem to work as per Rodrigo's comment.

Comment: Not working. But with the idea, I rewrite the FullCalendar only for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the example you have submitted you have set your script executing on the load event

```
$(window).load(function() {
      //your code
});
```

Take a look at the upper left corner of JsFiddle, either you have to set the fiddle running on document ready event and remove the unnecessary wrapping of `$(document).ready()` or just wrap your code in the `<head>` of your document.
Take a look at your update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ppnw3/1/ as well as the full demo provided in github
http://jsfiddle.net/Ppnw3/2/

Comment: Your example on jsfiddle is not showing any annotations